# Invalid read of size - C valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
if (argc < 3) {
    printf("Aufruf: %s <anzahl> <bundesland>\n", argv[0]);
    printf("Beispiel: %s 100 Bayern\n", argv[0]);
    printf("Klein-/Großschreibung beachten!\n");
    exit(1);
}
int anzahl = atoi(argv[1]);
char *bundesland = argv[2];

// Statisch allokierter Speicher
char staedte[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
char laender[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
int bewohner[MAX_LAENGE_ARR];

int len = read_file("staedte.csv", staedte, laender, bewohner);

// Hier implementieren
int x=0;
int d=0;
//int b=0;
//char* zeile_array=(char*) malloc (len * sizeof(char));
char *zeile_array[50];
char *zeile;
zeile=(char*) malloc(100); //allocating memory
    for(x=0;x<len;x++)
    {
        if(strcmp(laender[x],bundesland) == 0 && bewohner[x] >= anzahl)
        {
            sprintf(zeile, "Die Stadt %p hat %d Einwohner.",staedte[x],bewohner[x]);
            zeile_array[d]=zeile;   // putting it into array
            d=d+1;
        }
    }
//b++;
}
write_file(zeile_array,d);
free(zeile);
}
```

input3.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "input3.h"

int MAX_LAENGE_STR = 255;
int MAX_LAENGE_ARR = 100;

void write_file(char *result[], int len) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("resultat.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL){
        perror("resultat.txt");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", result[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int read_file(char *dateiname, char staedte[][MAX_LAENGE_STR], char      laender[][MAX_LAENGE_STR], int bewohner []) {
FILE *fp = fopen(dateiname, "r");

if (fp == NULL){
    perror(dateiname);
    exit(1);
}

char stadt[MAX_LAENGE_STR];
char land[MAX_LAENGE_STR];
int anzahl;
int i = 0;
int len;

while(fscanf(fp, "\"%[^\"]\";\"%[^\"]\";%d\n", stadt, land, &anzahl) != EOF)
{
    if (i >= MAX_LAENGE_ARR) {
        printf("ERROR: Die Datei ist größer als erwartet!");
        return i;
    }
    len = strlen(land) + 1;
    strncpy(laender[i], land, len-1);
    laender[i][len-1] = '\0';

    len = strlen(stadt) + 1;
    strncpy(staedte[i], stadt, len-1);
    staedte[i][len-1] = '\0';

    bewohner[i] = anzahl;
    i++;
}
fclose(fp);
return i;
}
```

input3.h:

```
extern int MAX_LAENGE_ARR;
extern int MAX_LAENGE_STR;

void write_file(char *result[], int len);
int read_file(char *dateiname, char staedte[][MAX_LAENGE_STR], char `laender[][MAX_LAENGE_STR], int bewohner []);
```

`

```
Invalid read of size 2
==23056==    at 0x4EC361B: __GI_mempcpy (memcpy.S:83)
==23056==    by 0x4EB054C: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1320)
==23056==    by 0x4E82904: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1661)
==23056==    by 0x4E8B336: fprintf (fprintf.c:32)
==23056==    by 0x400EE0: write_file (input3.c:17)
==23056==    by 0x400E52: main (d.c:56)
==23056==  Address 0x51fc391 is 33 bytes inside a block of size 100 free'd
==23056==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-  amd64-linux.so)
==23056==    by 0x400E14: main (d.c:50)
```

first 4 lines of staedte.csv:

```
"Berlin";"Berlin";3460725 
"Hamburg";"Hamburg";1786448 
"MÃ¼nchen";"Bayern";1353186
"KÃ¶ln";"Nordrhein-Westfalen";1007119
"Frankfurt am Main";"Hessen";679664
```

I just wanted to write some string into a new file but im getting everytime the same memory error.
I cant help myself
I need help to fix this error guys.
I dont know how top fix it and im desperate.

Comment: i intended to write a sting into my array and this agin and again until i reach the end of my for loop
then i wanted to write this string into a new file and after that free the memory which i allocated before

Comment: You must be joking. A *screenshot* of *text*? If you spent one minute on this website, you would realize that you can actually *post text* in your question!

Comment: ye sry guys, im just desperated :/, i posted some text

Comment: @Testrax Your code does not compile

Comment: You need to `malloc` memory for each of the strings you create, since your string storage is an array of pointers.

Comment: and how do i do this? @Weather Vane

Comment: Whats is `read_file`, what is `write_file`, what are your constants `MAX_LAENGE_...`. Please post a [MCVE]. And please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is this your own code? I ask because you are already doing what I suggested, but only once.

Comment: And show us the first 3-4 lines of your `staedte.csv` file. We need morew information otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: oke now all alright?

Comment: @Testrax better, but your code still doesn't compile. What is `input3.h` ? If you want help please post code we can copy paste and compile on our computers. Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ?? And please tell us what the output is supposed to be.

Comment: ye i did read this but input.h is just a header file but ye ok will post it too

Comment: @Testrax just post everything that is needed so we can compile and execute your code on our computers.

Comment: ye now sry for the cirumstances

Comment: @Testrax your code in the very first part of your question __does not compile__.

Comment: gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall d.c input3.c -o ckurs_blatt07_aufgabe02

it compile with this setting

Comment: OK, it certainly compiles on __your__ computer, but what you posted in your question is not exactly what you have on your computer.

Comment: can i somehow post my files or upload them?

Comment: Just put them into the question.

Comment: how? i cant drag them into it :/

Comment: @Testrax, just succeeded to compile your software after founding an unexpected `}` in the `main()` just after comment `//b++;`. Your input samples doesn't allow to have more one line in the output file.

Comment: No, you can't drag them, put you can copy/paste them just as you did with `input3.h`. But never mind, after some guesswork I managed to patch everything together, compile and run it. So far I couldn't detect any problems.

Comment: First problem found: `"Die Stadt %p hat %d Einwohner."` -> you need to replace the `%p` by `%s`, but that's is unrelated to the problem you have.

Comment: mmh oke, the error message says that im trying to read memory out of an freed block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here after is a proposed solution in `main()` :

List of the corrected errors and enhancements:

1- in the formatting output, replace `%p` (dedicated to pointers) by `%s` (dedicated to strings).

2- before storing in the output string `zeile_array[d]` allocate it to the len of the output text `zeile` including the null-terminator.

3- instead of copying output text pointer `zeile` to the output string `zeile_array[d]`, use the `strcpy()` function to move all characters.

4- to simplify, modify the temporary string `zeile` from char pointer dynamically allocate in the memory by a simple char array allocated automatically in the stack.

5- to protect, stop the extraction of result when all items of the array `char *zeile_array[50];` have been used. Or simply allocate enough array by using the `MAX_LAENGE_ARR` constante.

```
// Hier implementieren
int x=0;
int d=0;
//int b=0;
//char* zeile_array=(char*) malloc (len * sizeof(char));
char *zeile_array[MAX_LAENGE_ARR]; // instead of char *zeile_array[50];
char zeile[100];
// zeile=(char*) malloc(100); // allocated memory not needed
for(x=0;x<len;x++)
{
    if(strcmp(laender[x],bundesland) == 0 && bewohner[x] >= anzahl)
    {
        // as Micheal Walz said, replace %p by %s
        sprintf(zeile, "Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner.",staedte[x],bewohner[x]);
        // allocate the storing item
        zeile_array[d]=(char *)malloc(strlen(zeile)+1);
        // copy the formatted text into the storing item
        strcpy(zeile_array[d],zeile);   // putting it into array
        d=d+1;
        // abort research when output array is full
        if (d >= MAX_LAENGE_ARR) break;
    }
}
//b++;
//} // remove unexpected end of block
write_file(zeile_array,d);
// free the allocated memory only
for(x=0;x<d;x++)
{
    free(zeile_array[x]);
}
// free(zeile); is no more needed
```

Comment: Here `zeile=(char*) malloc(100);` and `free(zeile)` are pointless. `zeile=(char*) malloc(100);` and `free(zeile);` should be removed and `char *zeile` should be transformed into `char zeile[100];`

Comment: There is still a problem if the output has more then 50 lines. This limitation could either be circumvented by growing the `zeile_array` with `realloc` as needed, or by writing the lines directly into the output file, but maybe the usage of the `write_file` function is a requirement.

Comment: ... and an explanation of what was wrong in the OP's code would be nice too. Then the answer is worth an upvote.

Comment: Ye sry had to check this answers result

It worked out guys, ty very much :D

I appreciate your help and ty for your gzuidance

next time i will instantly make a proper question :D

and i fixed the remaining errors myself :D

Comment: @MichaelWalz added details not only in the source code.